# How can I optimise my MySQL query? I'm using CASE WHEN THEN

Tags: mysql

I'm making Data Warehouse. To load the table I'm using CASE WHEN THEN. I can load 100 rows using LIMIT 100 no problems. It is fast.
But to load full table 33 787 rows I receive errors:

Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query
Error Code: 1205. Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

My DBA suggested to optimise query. Can you please, suggest a solution?

Kind regards,
Anna

```
INSERT INTO dw_coder_fact 
            (age, 
             gender, 
             country_citizen, 
             country_live, 
             city_population, 
             is_ethnic_minority, 
             language_at_home, 
             degree_type_id, 
             school_major, 
             marital_status_id, 
             has_children, 
             children_number, 
             employment_status, 
             employment_field_id, 
             is_software_dev, 
             months_programming, 
             is_underemployed, 
             income, 
             survey_date, 
             date_id, 
             attended_bootcamp, 
             bootcamp_fulljob_after, 
             bootcamp_postsalary, 
             hours_learning, 
             bootcamploanyesno, 
             money_for_learning, 
             has_student_debt, 
             student_debt_owe, 
             has_debt, 
             has_home_mortgage, 
             home_mortgage_owe, 
             financially_supporting, 
             has_financially_dependents, 
             job_apply_when, 
             type_of_company_pref, 
             job_role_interest, 
             job_where_pref, 
             expected_earning) 
SELECT s.age, 
       s.gender, 
       s.countrycitizen, 
       s.countrylive, 
       s.citypopulation, 
       s.isethnicminority, 
       s.languageathome, 
       CASE s.schooldegree 
         WHEN "associate's degree" THEN 1 
         WHEN "bachelor's degree" THEN 2 
         WHEN 'high school diploma or equivalent (GED)' THEN 3 
         WHEN "master's degree (non-professional)" THEN 4 
         WHEN 'no high school (secondary school)' THEN 5 
         WHEN 'Ph.D.' THEN 6 
         WHEN 'professional degree (MBA, MD, JD, etc.)' THEN 7 
         WHEN 'some college credit, no degree' THEN 8 
         WHEN 'some high school' THEN 9 
         WHEN 'trade, technical. or vocational training' THEN 10 
         ELSE 11 
       end AS DegreeTypeDescription, 
       s.schoolmajor, 
       CASE s.maritalstatus 
         WHEN 'divorced' THEN 1 
         WHEN 'married or domestic partnership' THEN 2 
         WHEN 'separated' THEN 3 
         WHEN 'single, never married' THEN 4 
         WHEN 'widowed' THEN 5 
         ELSE 6 
       end AS MaritalStatusDescription, 
       s.haschildren, 
       s.childrennumber, 
       s.employmentstatus, 
       CASE s.employmentfield 
         WHEN 'architecture or physical engineering' THEN 1 
         WHEN 'arts, entertainmant, sports, or media' THEN 2 
         WHEN 'constraction and extraction' THEN 3 
         WHEN 'education' THEN 4 
         WHEN 'farming, fishing, and forestry' THEN 5 
         WHEN 'finance' THEN 6 
         WHEN 'food and beverage' THEN 7 
         WHEN 'health care' THEN 8 
         WHEN 'law enforcement and fire and rescue' THEN 9 
         WHEN 'legal' THEN 10 
         WHEN 'office and administrative support' THEN 11 
         WHEN 'sales' THEN 12 
         WHEN 'software development' THEN 13 
         WHEN 'software development and IT' THEN 14 
         WHEN 'transportation' THEN 15 
         ELSE 16 
       end AS EmploymentFieldDescription, 
       s.issoftwaredev, 
       s.monthsprogramming, 
       s.isunderemployed, 
       s.income, 
       s.part1starttime, 
       t.date_id, 
       s.attendedbootcamp, 
       s.bootcampfulljobafter, 
       s.bootcamppostsalary, 
       s.hourslearning, 
       s.bootcamploanyesno, 
       s.moneyforlearning, 
       s.hasstudentdebt, 
       s.studentdebtowe, 
       s.hasdebt, 
       s.hashomemortgage, 
       s.homemortgageowe, 
       s.financiallysupporting, 
       s.hasfinancialdependents, 
       s.jobapplywhen, 
       s.jobpref, 
       s.jobroleinterest, 
       s.jobwherepref, 
       s.expectedearning 
FROM   new_coders_survey_data s, 
       dw_time_dim t;
```

Comment: Start with [`Explain`ing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html) your SQL and showing us what this presents.

Comment: This insert statement into my table DW_CODER_FACT using SELECT. I have CASE statement to input ids into the columns as I will have description in my Dimension Tables.

Comment: You appear to be joining 2 tables with no constraints, which will generate a Cartesian product. is this deliberate or an error? 
FROM   new_coders_survey_data s, 
       dw_time_dim t;

Comment: @NickW Thank you. I've added WHEN clause. It fixes the problem